# Does Minecraft 1.8.8 use libudev.so.0?

Tags: java, minecraft

I had some issues launching several programs, such as Popcorn Time, Spotify, and Minecraft.. Both Popcorn Time and Spotify were fixed, in Popcorn Time I simply changed the hex code with ghex, in such that libudev.so.0 = libudev.so.1... I dont remember how I fixed Spotify.

Could this minecraft issue be related to the same subject?

( I should remind you that this is one of mein secondary computers, so its not a spec beast, its the exact opposite and that it runs Ubuntu MATE 15.04 )